# Issues : Selenium Automation on MSCRM2011

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation, dynamics-crm, selenium-rc

I am doing Selenium Automation testing On MSCRM 2011 but Save,Save&Cloase Buttons are not performing the Action
After filling (Child frame)the details in Fields(Attribute) i am switching to Parent frame . IS there any Issue with Ribbon Button in MSCRM2011

Answer (score 0):

Try to simulate a mouse event to perform the click operation. This could help you.

Comment: Thanks sir. I wrote Below Lines. 
  Actions obj2 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement ele =    driver.findElement(By.id("account|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.account.Save-Large"));
     obj2.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();


But these are working